# UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey Deprecated

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to use the code below however Xcode tells me UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated and I was wondering what the newer code was instead:

```
NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
```

And below is the code in context:

```
-(void) keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *)notif {


    NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];
    NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame; 
    viewFrame.size.height += keyboardSize.height;
    scrollView.frame = viewFrame;

    if (!keyboardVisible) {
        //NSLog(@"Keyboard is already hidden. Ignoring notification.");
        return;
    }

    keyboardVisible = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey or UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey key instead of UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey.

Comment: however, UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey etc. does not take into account the rotation, whereas UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey does